# How might one permanently change the key ability for the Craft skill from INT to DEX?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills

How might one permanently change the key ability for a specific skill from a mental to a physical stat?

Specifically the Craft skill, and from INT to DEX, relating to a character that can carve whatever they see but doesn't use intellect to do so as they are something of the classic Savant type which does not interface with the world through intellectual logic or thinking patterns.

I am ideally looking for a rule or mechanic that supports the concept, rather than just home-brewing something, if possible. If such a rule or mechanic doesn't exist, then knowing that is helpful too. And something that can be taken at as low a level as possible, be it feat, trait, feature, item, or power.

I am aware of the Void Disciple ability of *Void Release* which swaps primary stats for all purposes temporarily, however, taking 10 levels of a prestige class for a 3/d ability is very suboptimal, and does not meet my requirements. The Variant rule for alternate ability skill checks is DM dependent, therefore it may not work when moving the character between different groups and thus is likewise not what I'm looking for.

WotC officially approved materials only please; such as Dungeon, Dragon, Rokugan, Dragonlance, Kingdoms of Kalamar, Official Sites under the Official Site License, etc..

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Wizards of the Coast has no ownership stake in sites other than their own wizards.com. I assume you mean Athas.org; unless I am very much mistaken, that site is fully independent, it just has a licensing agreement with Wizards (which it secured thanks to the fact that a co-founder was a WotC employee). Anyway, the title is this question should really be specific to what you want; more general solutions would obviously cover this need and be an answer, but specificity is usually better, especially here where it would make a much simpler title.

Comment: Any material published on an Official Site is co-owned with WotC as per the Official Site license. The license further states that both the site AND WotC cannot do anything related to the 3rd edition of said campaign setting outside of said site. This is why some contend that such material counts as first-party, despite the fact that the site is not being actively maintained or managed by WotC. Also if the property is licensed by another company the Official Site license terminates, as happened with Ravenloft. WotC has not yet rescinded the Official Site license otherwise.

Comment: As far as the cons against the Official Site license goes, the WotC employees who created it no longer work there, their successors no longer work there, and WotC has not responded to any questions or requests from the Official Sites for many years, leading many to conclude it is no longer a thing; especially in light of the newer fan content licenses that have come out since.

Comment: Your final item in the list, then, would be far more clearly stated as “other sites under the Official Site License”—that would give anyone unfamiliar with the situation the keywords they need to learn more about it.

Comment: Thank you for that guidance. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

### I don't know everything but probably not possible

usually if this kind of stuff exists you can find it [here](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=4369.0)

But it seems like you are out of luck.
My best advice is to either lean into the intelligence aspect and play a Factotum, or you could take 2 levels of marshal and add your cha mod to all int checks, if you like that flavor better. Or talk to your DM of course.